# How to automatically set value for a text field based on value from another text field in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Postal Code"),
        TextField(
          controller: controllerPostalCode,
        ),

        // if controllerPostalCode not null
        Container(
            child: FutureBuilder<AddressCtrl>(   //Future Builder that hold data on State and Country
                future: getDataCtrl(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    if (snapshot.data.result == null) {
                      return Container();
                    } else {
                      return Container(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text("State"),
                            TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: snapshot.data.result[index].State // value will be display after user input Postal Code text field
                                  ),
                            ),
                            Text("Country"),
                            TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: snapshot.data.result[index].Country // value will be display after user input Postal Code text field
                                  ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  }
                })),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

I want to automatically input values to two text field (in this case: State and Country) based on value of user input on Postal Code text field without having to click on any button. I found many question regarding this issue but I couldn't find in Dart/Flutter.

Additional notes: The value of State and Country are from REST API.

Comment: Could you share some code that reproduce your issue?

Comment: @RodolfoFranco I have add some code of what I want to do

Comment: The problem is that the value of State and Country did not appear exactly after I input the Postal Code textfield. I do not want to click on any button.

Comment: Use onTextChanged method in potal code and setState to change thee variable that holding the text. Then use it where you want.

Comment: Ohh.. Thank you @ShadyBoshra ! I will try to use onTextChanged now.

Comment: Okay, I will make it as an answer now, if it did work, please mark it as correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `onTextChanged` method in postal code and `setState` to change the variable that holding the text from postal code text field. Then use it (the variable) where you want.

And this [doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes) will help you more and more.

Hope I could help you.

Comment: Thank you @ShadyBoshra for you sharing! Really appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcomed any time. Hope to enjoy in Stackoverflow community.

Answer (score 1):

use in text

```
var textController = new TextEditingController();
```